# Regex to check if multiple files exist using one if then statement

Tags: bash

Just need some help tweaking my command. I just want to check if two files already exist (and are not empty) in my directory. I have the following command, and although it seems to work I get a weird error (or maybe not an error) stating the following.

```
for files in *.bam
do
    PREFIX=${files%%_aln*}
    if [ -s ${PREFIX}_R[1,2].fastq ]   # <-- the R[1,2] is giving an issue
    then
         echo 'Skip'
    else
         do something
    fi
done
```

But when the files do exist, I get this message:

```
-bash: [: sample_21_R1.fastq: binary operator expected
-bash: [: sample_22_R1.fastq: binary operator expected
-bash: [: sample_23_R1.fastq: binary operator expected
```

If I get rid of the [1,2] and change it to just R1 or R2, I get no errors. But I want to check if either of those files exist. How to change the expression?

Comment: What's wrong with `-s file1 -o -s file2`?

Comment: I just want to check if two files already exist ... can you explain your code.

Comment: Was unaware of the -o operator...that would make it a lot easier. My code, simply check if either version of a file exists, if it does not then I have to run a command that will create whichever is missing.

Comment: `-s` will check *a specific filename*, not a filename pattern. Also, the pattern `[1,2]` will match "1", "2", or a literal comma; I think you want `[12]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't working because you're trying to do two checks in one.

Try changing this line

```
 if [ -s ${PREFIX}_R[1,2].fastq ]
```

to this

```
if [ -s ${PREFIX}_R1.fastq ] && [ -s ${PREFIX}_R2.fastq ]; then
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash): read the glob pattern expansion into an array, and if the size of the array is greater than zero, then files exist.

```sh
shopt -s nullglob

for file in *.bam
do
    prefix=${file%%_aln*}
    fastq_files=( "$prefix"_R[12].fastq )
    if (( ${#fastq_files[@]} > 0 ))
    then
         echo 'Skip'
    else
         do_something
    fi
done
```

Comment: Note that this isn't quite equivalent, because it doesn't check the files' sizes, just whether any exist. Also, I always recommend turning off `nullglob` (with `shopt -u nullglob`) afterward, to avoid unexpected behavior like `grep somepattern *.txt` reading from stdin, rather than just not finding any matches.